# How to get Accessibility Service Gesture JUST from only My app

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I want to listen to accessibility gesture when user inside my app. It means onGusture should call when My App is at foreground but onGesture always called no matter my app at foreground or not.  I try to set package name in Java as well as in XML but it's not working. Please take look at this tell me what I am doing wrong

**MyAccessibilityService.java**

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
private String TAG="MyAccessibilityServiceTAG";


    @Override
    protected boolean onGesture(int gestured) {//This method always called, I want this method only called when my App in foreground  
        Log.d(TAG,"onGesture:"+gestureId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gesture: "+gestureId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onGesture(gestureId);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Event Occurred");
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: event=" + event);
        AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
        if (null == nodeInfo) return;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
                AccessibilityServiceInfo info = getServiceInfo();
        // your other assignments
        info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.vorail.ttsdemo"};
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Accessibility Interrupted" );

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"Service Destroyed");
    }
}
```

accessibility_service_config.xml

```
 <accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                           android:description="@string/app_name"
                           android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeTouchExplorationGestureStart"
                           android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="false"

                           android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
                           android:packageNames="com.vorail.ttsdemo"
                           android:notificationTimeout="100"
                           android:settingsActivity="com.vorail.ttsdemo.MainActivity"
                           android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode"
                           android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    />
```

Comment: Why are you using an accessibility service? Activities and their views get touch events and can handle gestures. So, if you only want gestures from your own activities and views, you do not need an accessibility service.

Comment: I  tried setOnTouchListener  with my activity view but the problem is when talkback on it consumes one finger gesture  before my app consume

Comment: Isn't the solution, then, to provide some alternative way of using your app, that does not involve gestures, for the benefit of those needing Talkback? AFAIK, gesture-based UIs are not particularly friendly for the visually impaired.

Comment: this app for blind people.

Answer (score 3):

By setting `android:packageNames` to something specific to your app, you'll filter the incoming events:

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused|typeTouchInteractionStart|typeTouchInteractionEnd|typeTouchExplorationGestureStart|typeTouchExplorationGestureEnd"
    android:packageNames="com.app.yourapplication"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" />
```